# Dynamic Config Loading in Camel Application Bundle in Karaf 3.0.5

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi, apache-servicemix, aries

I have a simple Camel Application bundle which is to be deployed in Karaf 3.0.5 under Apache Service Mix 6.1. The configuration file is placed in `etc/` directory (let's say it is named as `wf.cfg`). I want to have the dynamic config change functionality in my application bundle. So that whenever something is changed in `wf.cfg` it is immediately available to bundle. For this I have added the following in my
`blueprint.xml`

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="wf"
    update-strategy="reload">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="env" value="local" />
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>

<!-- a bean that uses a blueprint property placeholder -->
<bean id="configBean" class="com.jabong.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.config.ConfigBean">
        <property name="env" value="${env}" />
</bean>
```

The problem I am facing now is if the `update-strategy` is set to `reload`. Then it seems to be reloading the entire bean.

Can someone let me know is there a way I can reload only the `configBean` not the entire bundle? If I can achieve this then may be I can have some static reference to the config variables inside the `configBean` which my application bundle can then make use of?

The full `blueprint.xml` is placed [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b7482ab89766a57b162d).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `property-placeholder` can have two values for the `update-strategy` :

1. **reload**: The blueprint container is reloaded asynchronously when the properties change. Any property change stops the context (and shutdown camel), and restarts it with the new property. everything is done automatically.
2. **none**: Nothing is done. The context is not shutdown (and so camel), but the properties are not injected. The property change are lost

There is another way to inject properties in Aries-Blueprint, through `managed-properties` : They decorate a bean definition, and dynamically inject the new property into the bean when the configuration change. There are here two modes : `bean-managed` (invoke a method when the configuration change) and `container-managed` (invoke a setter when a property change).

With this `managed-properties` you can dynamically intercept change in the configuration, and respond to it, without restarting the blueprint context (and consequently without stopping the camel context).

However, components in camel are not so dynamics : They read the configuration when an endpoint is created, but that's all. If you want to change the configuration of the route dynamically, it's not easy or impossible. You will have to stop/start the route.

Comment: Can you please point me to "aries blueprint" / camel  documentation where `managed-properties` are explained?

Comment: Honestly, the documentation of Aries is really small/deprecated, and `managed-properties` is not part of blueprint, it's an extension of Aries. You can however check the sources and the tests, for example : https://github.com/apache/aries/blob/trunk/blueprint/blueprint-itests/src/test/resources/ManagedServiceFactoryTest.xml

Comment: The link has changed: https://github.com/apache/aries/blob/trunk/blueprint/itests/blueprint-itests/src/test/resources/ManagedServiceFactoryTest.xml